# What is the best way to automate windows azure deployment?

Tags: deployment, azure

Newbie to automated azure deployment here! I have the happy task of automating our deployment to the cloud. I have also done some reading and discovered that the 2 main tools are MSbuild and Powershell. Please could anyone tell me why i would use one over the other or indeed if there are any better ways to automate the deployment. Keeping in mind that my main concern is performance and i need this deplymrnt to be as fast as possible.

Any insight would be most welcome.

Comment: As of February 2017 - If you/team are a visual studio developer; then you should not look at CI/CD features offered by VS2017 - and its as easy as breeze with few clicks if your code repo is VSTS (TFS)

Answer (score 9):

I'm a fan of using PowerShell for deployments.  It's pretty quick to set up and the script can be pretty straight forward.

MSBuild can be great too.  I use MSBuild from TFS Team Build to kick off a PowerShell script to do the deployment.  Works like a champ.

A good starting point would be http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2011/12/06/automated-build-and-deployment-with-windows-azure-sdk-1-6.aspx.  This blog does a great job of showing you how to build and deploy with Team Build.

If you don't want/need the Team Build and MSBuild part, then just look at his PowerShell script.  That covers the basics of getting a deployment from your dev environment to Windows Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Web Deploy, it only takes about a minute to deploy a fix. See these links

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud/archive/2011/04/19/enabling-web-deploy-for-windows-azure-web-roles-with-visual-studio.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/funkyonex/Speed-Up-Azure-Deployments-with-the-New-Web-Deployment-Feature

Answer (score -1):

At SplendidCRM, we had a similar need to automate deployments to Azure, but as our need was to service our live customers, we had to develop using C#.  We have been watching Azure for many years, but it was not until they provided a DNS service did it make sense to make the move.  Using the Azure Resource Manager (ARM) libraries, we were able to automate VM creation, SQL database creation and DNS name creation. In addition to the Microsoft documentation for ARM, we found it particularly useful to be able to get the Microsoft source code for the PowerShell scripts that wrap ARM.  This is because the documentation does not always provide a complete set of settings.

In the end, we decided to release the Azure deployment code as part of a new Ultimate edition that combines order and customer management with software deployment.